# Git Hub not showing my Organization's Repositories in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, github, oauth, version-control

My Android Studio is not showing my organization's repositories when I try to create a new "Project from Version Control".

It only lists my personal repositories, but I am a member of the organization and member of the organization's repositories too.

I am logged to my Git Hub account in Android Studio and it shows my 2 repositories, but it only shows 1 of 5 of my organization's repositories. The other 4 repositories are missing.[image: logged]

I already tried to log in using token, removed the policy, added again, and it never shows the rest.

I also created a new repository to test and this empty repository shows up in Android Studio. The other repository that is also showing does not have forks or branches and is a basic repository to store some libs. It is the one detailed in green.

I have checked my Third-party application access policy and it looks correct too:
[image: Third-party application access policy]

It looks like some permission to the other 4 repositories is not correct or has lost some kind of authentication or authorization, but I can't figure out what it is.

Any insight??